# why my custom gravatar not showing up on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can you please anyone help me my custom gravatar not showing up on wordpress if i use plugin its working fine and one more thing i check it on loacalhost. Is it possible to not working in local. Below is my code.

// customize default gravatars

```
function custom_gravatars($avatar_defaults) {

    // add another custom gravatar
    $customGravatar3 = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/default-avatar.jpg';
    $avatar_defaults[$customGravatar3] = 'Custom gravatar';

    return $avatar_defaults;
}
add_filter('avatar_defaults', 'custom_gravatars');
```

[image]
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install it before It shows up. Here are easy steps to proceed:

1- **A**ccess your ftp > Go to Folder > wp-content > Themes > In this folder open up the theme folder you are currently using.

2- **O**pen up **functions.php** > Add the code bellow after the opening `<?php`

Code:

```
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'newgravatar' );
function newgravatar ($avatar_defaults) {
$myavatar = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/custom-gravatar.gif';
$avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "You Name here or Website Name";
return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

3- **U**pload your custom gravatar image "custom-gravatar.gif" to your theme directory.

4- **F**inally, login to your WordPress Admin Panel and click on Settings > Discussion > Select your custom gravatar.

Comment: Sorry, but i already used this code and i mansion too. So please tell me its only working on live only ? it's not working in localhost ?

Comment: Thanks for answer i got issue. issue was default avatar not working in localhost. when i upload code in live its working fine. :)